# Why are the values from FB.Canvas.getPageInfo() returning all zeros

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Why are the values from the call to FB.Canvas.getPageInfo() are returning all zeros?

```
function scrollElementIntoView(elementTop, elementBottom) {
    var pageInfo = FB.Canvas.getPageInfo();// 0 0 0 0 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a timeout on setting that variable. Not a clean solution but timeouts have saved my ass with Facebook stuff more times that I can count

Comment: Are you saying to set a timeout to make sure the page has loaded? I'm calling this well after the page has loaded. I'm testing this on our dev server. Does it have to be on the FB site to run?

Answer (score 2):

`FB.Canvas.getPageInfo()` will return immediately the last found page information and therefore if this is the first time you have called it on the page it will return as expected '0 0 0 0'. You will have to provide the function with a callback to execute in order to get it to work how you wish.

Try this:

```
function scrollElementIntoView(elementTop, elementBottom) {
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info) {
        var pageInfo = info;

        // ...rest of your code
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks nav. I've finished the project but no longer am able to verify this. For future visitors it may also be solved by running from the facebook site.

Comment: Sure no problem - more info regarding this here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/543/